# Github - reverting a pull

Tags: git, github, pull

I am working on a repository forked from another public repo. Recently I did a git pull from origin. Now I want to remove the latest pull that I made. I executed the command

```
git reset --keep HEAD@{1}
```

After that, when I tried to push,
It says that

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/branchName' by xx commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

Do I need to remove pull from remote as well? If so how could it be done? Please explain.

Comment: Force push if you think the origin's branch is in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you really want to is to push no matter that the branch is ahead. You don't really need to delete the commit, You can just use force push.

git push origin  --force

Comment: also, for safety, consider `--force-with-lease` option